# Good template for server side programmer that is horrible at css and design?

Tags: php, html, templates, css

Hi All To The Wise People!!

My question is, I am a php/javascript programmer. I do well on the logic side of things, server side... But when it comes to design, arty stuff, css etc... I am just absolutely horrible.
Does anyone have any suggestions on a template or something that I can use that will have created nice cool styles already for me that I just have to plugin my php/js into, and maybe choose from style or what not...

Basically I'm trying to get around having to actually spend countless hours of design and playing with css to get stuff to work, and then it wont even look nice... And instead just have a program or script or something do it all for me...

I would prefer a free open source project... but if its a really good app, I would be open to paying for it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Templates are mostly _for_ something, like a CMS. You can find \infty templates for wordpress etc. What you want is just a plain html website? I'm not sure what kind of app you want to find that gives a template but no code. Apart from that, I don't think this is a really answerable question (more like polling, debate, etc, and no real facts possible for "what is a cool looking website") ?

Comment: @user1403127 same prob here ..looking for some fruitful answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should take a lot at twitter's [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), it's a toolkit that comes with a lot of HTML and CSS resources, as well as a grid template to help you build your website.
It's very useful to build beautiful user interfaces and can help a lot if you're a non-designer trying to do fast-yet-beautiful UIs.

Comment: I have used Bootstrap in few projects and am really pleased with it, it takes out most of the work from designing. Highly recommended.

Comment: yes i just tried it out and i like it... its exactly what i was looking for!!